# XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX different default font features

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec

The following MWE is producing different outputs on XeLaTeX and LuaLateX:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FoglihtenNo04-070.otf}

\begin{document}

ffi ew
\end{document}
```

XeLateX:
[image: XeLaTex output]

LuaLaTeX:
[image: LuaLaTex output]

Is this the intended outcome?

The font I chose for testing came from http://www.glukfonts.pl/font.php?l=de&font=FoglihtenNo04.

Comment: It seems that in XeTeX the stylistic set 1 is selected by default. If I set the font feature `ss01` in LuaTeX I get the same result as you with XeTeX.

Comment: You are right, but how could I deactivate ss01 with XeLaTeX? And is this the intended behavior of fontspec/XeLaTex?

Comment: I use neither XeTeX, nor fontspec. But according to [Controlling fontspec…](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27196/controlling-fontspec-to-use-certain-font-features-for-different-fonts-in-one-doc) you could try `\fontspec[RawFeature={-ss01}]{FoglihtenNo04-070.otf}`. The question is *why* this is feature set by default. As a user I would not expect this. I don't know enough about OpenType to tell you if the font designer can set particular features as default. But even then, there is still the question why LuaTeX and XeTeX differ.

Answer (score 12):

XeLaTeX renders it correctly. The "w" in "ew" comes from Contextual Alternates [`calt`], a feature that is turned on by default in XeLateX (XeTeX). The Stylistic Set 01 [`ss01`] feature can be turned ON (for every "w" in text), but it is not the default.

It seems that LuaLaTeX works only with Standard Ligatures [`liga`] as default, but not with Contextual Alternates [`calt`].

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I've taken the liberty of editing your message for better clarity. You may consider to register in order to give more contributions to the site.